# How to push multiples of a number to array?

Tags: javascript

How would one push multiples of a number to an array? For example, if the input is (6), I want to create an array that holds `[6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, etc...]`

The most intuitive method to me does not work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    firstArray.push(arr[0] *= 2);
}
```

This multiplies the number that comes before it by 2, causing an exponential growth. [14, 28, 56, 112, 224, 448, 896, 1792, etc.]

How would one achieve this?

Comment: `firstArray.push(6 * (i+1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem in the code, as commented by Pranav is the use of multiplication by two in the `for` loop.

Using `i` iterator index can solve the problem.

```
firstArray.push(6 * (i + 1));
```

As `i` is starting from `0`, `i + 1` will give the number which is *1-based*.

---

**Another Approach:**

First add the number

```
var num = 6,
    arr = [num];
```

Then add the number which is double of the previous in the array.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(arr[i - 1] + num);
}
```

```js
var arr = [6];

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(arr[i - 1] + arr[0]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

---

The same thing can also be done in single line using `for` loop.

```js
var arr = [];
for (let i = 0, num = 6; i < 10; i++, num += 6) {
  arr.push(num);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
function multiplyArrayElement(num) {
    return num * 2;
}
numbers = [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36];

newArray = numbers.map(multiplyArrayElement);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/25c4ff6y/

Answer (score 1):

It's cleaner to use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Just beware of its browser support.

```
Array.from({length: 10},(v,i) => (i + 1) * 6)
```

Comment: Why I didn't think of that. ^1

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  firstArray.push(arr[0] * (i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
var x = 6;   //Your desired input number
var z; 
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    z = (x*i);
    arr.push(z);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

"One line" solution with `Array.fill` and `Array.map` functions:

```
var num = 6;

var arr = new Array(10).fill(0).map(function(v, k){ return num *(k + 1); });

console.log(arr); // [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
```